# Unable to start a network connection due to a network configuration issue: https://api.revenuecat.com/v1/receipts

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription, revenuecat

I've integrated google in-app subscription using revenuecat.
Getting this error
[image]

Subscription is completed successfully on frontend but not updating in backend. Not found any record in revenuecat transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who face  this issue, I've solved this error. The mistake was I put invalid **package name** in revenuecat for my project. The package name on google play console and on revenuecat were different. When corrected the name on revenuecat it worked like a charm.

you can find your package name in app-level build.gradle file
it should be like this

**com.domainname.appname**

Comment: This is not working for me.